# Sitecore: How to Change a Virtual User's Username?

Tags: sitecore

In Sitecore, is it possible to change a virtual user's username? Either via the User Manager in the UI, or programmatically?

Answer (score 5):

When working with virtual users in Sitecore, the users themselves are never actually stored in the Sitecore system. Once a virtual user has been logged out, the user's record does not persist. However, once the virtual user has been created you can use Sitecore's Security APIs to set any Profile properties or Roles to the it. Note that you must do this *before* the virtual user is logged in.

If you would like to assign a particular username to a user, you must do it *before* creating the virtual user. Usernames in Sitecore cannot be changed after being created. If you are looking to change the username, you should create a new virtual user with the same properties and roles, log out the current virtual user and log in the new one.

Comment: This seems to be true for other user profile properties on virtual users (not just username), modifying profile properties and hitting .Save() does not persist the change nor throw any exception.